# Store data RESTfull API 404 not found

Tags: laravel

I am new to API and I try to store data in database. when I try to store I will get 404 not found

APIUserController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    
    $user = new User();
    $user->id = $request['id'];
    $user->Id_staff = $request['Id_staff'];
    $user->name = $request['name'];
    $user->noIc = $request['noIc'];
    $user->email = $request['email'];
    $user->password = bcrypt($request['password']);
    $user->pusat_tangungjawab = $request['pusat_tangungjawab'];
    $user->jawatan = $request['jawatan'];    
    $user->user_group = $request['user_group'];
    $user->user_level = $request['user_level'];
    $user->phone_no = $request['phone_no'];
    $user->save();

    return new UserResource($user);  
}
```

api.php

```
Route::post('user/store', 'APIUserController@store');
```

[api route and data required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuHur.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGWXQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check the following:

1. Make sure your api routes have the "api" prefix.  You can run

   php artisan route:list

in the console to be sure.

2. 404 Error may refer to a route not found, but also to a Resource not found.  I would comment out the last line of your controller just to make sure.
3. Check that the route is under the VerifyCSRF exception (may be unrelated)

Comment: route list are true  POST     | api/user/store                       |                   | App\Http\Controllers\APIUserController@store            | api